# Obtener GPS Activo en Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

necesito mostrar un mensaje por pantalla al obtener la posición GPS.
Es decir cuando encuentre la posición donde nos encontramos, que esto lo podemos ver porque en nuestro menú de notificaciones pone Ubicación definida por GPS, mientras cuando no tiene la posición muestra Buscando GPS.
Quiero que cuando cambie de buscando GPS a Ubicación definida por GPS pueda mostrar al usuario un Toast diciendo que la Ubicación se ha encontrado.
El código es el siguiente:

```
public class Inicio extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button startButton;
    Location mLastLocation = null;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LatLng latLng = null;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    boolean cambiar = true;
    boolean conectado = false;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //Creamos el mapa
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        //nuevas coordenadas
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if(cambiar){
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
            cambiar=false;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        //Tomamos la posicion cada 1segundos
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        //establecer explícitamente el intervalo más rápido para las actualizaciones de ubicación
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        //Prioridad compensada para no gastar mucha bateria
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Inicio extends FragmentActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Location mLastLocation;//guarda la ultima ubicación 


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Nueva ubicación: (%s, %s)",
            location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mLastLocation = location;
    showMessage(mLastLocation);
}

private void showMessage(Location loc) {
    if (loc != null) {
            double lat = loc.getLatitude();
            double lng = loc.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity()," lat:" +lat+", lon:"+lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}



}
```

Comment: Cuida con la escritura: private :)

Comment: No es exactamente lo que me refería. A lo que me refiero es a mostrar un mensaje cuando la conexión se establezca, no ha mostrar un mensaje cada vez que cambia de posición. De esta forma aunque me pone aún Buscando GPS, me salta el Toast

Comment: Mi respuesta fue según lo que leí.  Cuando dices que 'la conexión se establezca' me imagino que te refieres a que encuentre una posición (latitud y longitud) definitiva. Si es así, tu tienes que manejar cuando obtener esa posición definitiva y luego inhabilitar el uso de GPS.

Comment: El método que te da la ubicación al principio es onConnected, luego el metodo onLocationChanged te da la ubicación cada vez que cambia de ubicación. Así que tu tienes que decidir cuando guardas la ubicación y si lo guardas la primera vez que se obtiene la posición, la segunda, o la n-esima Y luego inhabilitar el uso de GPS.